# jQuery UI Slider with two handles and moving them same time on touch device

Tags: html, jquery-ui, slider, touch

So I'm using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) slider and [jQuery UI Touch Punch library](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) so that the slider would work on touch devices as well. And it does work, party.

My slider is a range slider so it has two handles and I would need that user could adjust the slider using both handles same time on mobile/touch device (bit like pinch) but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Why it doesn't work or anyone have any advice how could I make it work? Code so far:

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 150,
      values: [ 50, 100 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
         // will update value here later
      }
 });
```

Am I missing some setting or is this some thing with jQuery UI / Touch punch or should I be using some other library? Any advice appreciated! :)

Comment: Anyone doesn't have any idea? :s

Comment: Really? Anyone would any advice where to look in code to get this working?